# How can I drop all triggers in a single database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, trigger

I have a database with 104 triggers, is there a way to delete all the triggers with a single command from a single database called 'system_db_audits?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

You can use Dynamic SQL and the `sys.triggers` DMV to build query that you can execute.

`is_ms_shipped` excludes any triggers that were shipped with SQL Server.
`parent_class_desc` filters for object level triggers, rather than database level.

Change the `PRINT` to an `EXEC` once you are happy with the output.

```
USE system_db_audits;
GO

DECLARE @sql NVARCHAR(MAX) = N'';

SELECT @sql += 
    N'DROP TRIGGER ' + 
    QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + N'.' + 
    QUOTENAME(t.name) + N'; ' + NCHAR(13)
FROM sys.triggers AS t
WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
  AND t.parent_class_desc = N'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN';

PRINT @sql;
```

Comment: will fail for larger sql strings, see for resolution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7850477/how-to-print-varcharmax-using-print-statement/10206672

Comment: "Change the `PRINT` to an `EXEC` once you are happy with the output." Note that for dynamic sql, parentheses must be used: `EXEC (@sql)`

Answer (score 6):

Use `Sys.Triggers` Meta Data Table which contains a row for each object that is a trigger

1. Change output mode to text by clicking the toolbar button shown here:

[image]

2. Execute this script:

   ```
   USE YourDBName
   GO
   SELECT ' GO ' + Char(10) + Char(13) + 'DROP TRIGGER ' 
       + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(O.[object_id])) + '.' 
       + QUOTENAME(name)
   FROM sys.sql_modules as M 
       INNER JOIN sys.triggers as O 
           ON M.object_id = O.object_id;
   ```
3. Copy Output into a new SQL Server Management Studio window, verify the code performs the actions you are expecting, and Execute.

Comment: Don't the `DROP TRIGGER` statements need terminators `;` though?

Comment: MSDN says: 
Transact-SQL statement terminator.Although the semicolon is not required for most statements in this version of SQL Server, it will be required in a future version.

Answer (score 2):

In case you want to run a sql job on a central server [ServerA] to do the trigger deletion work, 
I'll provide a PowerShell version assuming you have a SQL Server 2012 (or above) instance with SQLPS module installed on [ServerA]

Say you want to delete all triggers in [AdventureWorks] database on [ServerB] SQL Server instance (SQL Server 2005+).

You can run the following PS on [ServerA]:

```
import-module sqlps -DisableNameChecking;
$db=get-item -Path "sqlserver:\sql\ServerB\default\databases\AdventureWorks";

#before deletion, you can check that triggers do exist
$db.tables.triggers | select name

#now delete
$db.tables.triggers |Where-Object {-not $_.IsSystemObject } | foreach-object {$_.drop()};

#check after deletion
$db.tables.triggers | select name;
```

Please remember to replace **ServerB** and **AdventureWorks** with your own values.

This is pretty flexible solution which you can easily customize to adapt to other different requirements, such as only delete triggers belong to a specific set of tables, or disable (instead of delete) some specific triggers etc.

Strictly speaking, the solutions provided by @Mark Sinkinson is not correct because the requirement is **not** to delete triggers on 'system_db_audits' db, but to delete triggers in another db **from** 'system_db_audits'. This means you need to create a dynamic sql in 'system_db_audits' to wrap the "dynamic sql" provided by @Mark Sinkinson to delete those target triggers assuming that both 'system_db_audits' and the target db are on the same sql server instance. Otherwise if the two dbs are not on the same instance, it will be even much "ugly" to handle the deletion (such as via linked server etc). In such scenario, PS is an elegant solution no matter where the target db is or is not on the same sql instance.

Answer (score 0):

To take into account the limit of the string holding the sql string:

```
SET NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT OFF;
SET ANSI_PADDING, ANSI_WARNINGS, CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL, ARITHABORT, QUOTED_IDENTIFIER, ANSI_NULLS, NOCOUNT ON;
SET DATEFORMAT YMD;
SET XACT_ABORT ON;
SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE;
BEGIN TRANSACTION

DECLARE @items AS CURSOR
DECLARE @item AS nvarchar(250)

SET @items = CURSOR FOR SELECT N'DROP TRIGGER ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N'; ' 
    FROM sys.triggers AS t WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0 AND t.parent_class_desc = N'OBJECT_OR_COLUMN';

OPEN @items
FETCH NEXT FROM @items INTO @item
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN    
    EXEC (@item)
    FETCH NEXT FROM @items INTO @item
END 
CLOSE @items 
DEALLOCATE @items

COMMIT TRANSACTION;
```

For Views the SET command would be:

```
SET @items = CURSOR FOR SELECT N'DROP VIEW ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(r.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(r.name) + N'; '
FROM sys.views AS r WHERE r.is_ms_shipped = 0;
```

For Stored Procedures the SET command would be :

```
SET @items = CURSOR FOR SELECT N'DROP PROCEDURE ' + QUOTENAME(OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(t.object_id)) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.name) + N'; '
    FROM sys.procedures AS t WHERE t.is_ms_shipped = 0
```